# How to extract dictionaries from a JSON table

Tags: python, json, dictionary, robotframework

I am testing REst API using robot framework and requests library
A JSON response of an API is in a form of a table.
I am using robot framework to test this API and I would like to split this table into dictionaries so that I could use robot framework keyword to test the response.

Here is an example of my JSON response:

```
[
  {
      locale: "fr_FR",
      day: "2015-12-01",
      displayPricePerPerson: 9800,
      displayTotalPrice: 9800,
      promotion: false,
      minLos: 1
},
{
      locale: "fr_FR",
      day: "2015-12-02",
      displayPricePerPerson: 9800,
      displayTotalPrice: 9800,
      promotion: false,
      minLos: 1
 },
[
```

Ideally I would like to extract the whole response in form of dictionaries so that I could loop over the response and assert keys and values.

so instead of dictionaries embedded into a table I would have only dictionaries:

```
{
      locale: "fr_FR",
      day: "2015-12-01",
      displayPricePerPerson: 9800,
      displayTotalPrice: 9800,
      promotion: false,
      minLos: 1
},
{
      locale: "fr_FR",
      day: "2015-12-02",
      displayPricePerPerson: 9800,
      displayTotalPrice: 9800,
      promotion: false,
      minLos: 1
 },
```

I have tried with collections and requests library but I am getting an error :

```
${JSON}=  To JSON  ${resp.content}
${DICT}=  Convert To List  ${JSON}
 Log  ${DICT}
:FOR  ${KEY}  IN  locale  day  displayPricePerPerson  displayTotalPrice  promotion  minLos
          \   Run Keyword And Continue On Failure  List Should Contain Value  ${JSON}  ${KEY}

Error : ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
```

Comment: `convert to list` converts data to a list, not a dictionary. Why do you think it returns a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                you have dictionaries in your list already. though badly formed.they are missing quotes around the keys

                    lt = [
                      {
                          "locale": "fr_FR",
                          "day": "2015-12-01",
                          "displayPricePerPerson": 9800,
                          "displayTotalPrice": 9800,
                          "promotion": False,
                          "minLos": 1
                    },
                    {
                          "locale": "fr_FR",
                          "day": "2015-12-02",
                          "displayPricePerPerson": 9800,
                          "displayTotalPrice": 9800,
                          "promotion": False,
                          "minLos": 1
                     },
                    ]

                    for el in lt:
                        print(type(el))

                    <class 'dict'>
                    <class 'dict'>

                    d1 = lt[0]
                    d2 =lt[1]

                    print(d1.items())
                    dict_items([('day', '2015-12-01'), ('locale', 'fr_FR'), ('displayPricePerPerson', 9800), ('minLos', 1), ('promotion', False), ('displayTotalPrice', 9800)])

                    print(d2.items())
                    dict_items([('day', '2015-12-02'), ('locale', 'fr_FR'), ('displayPricePerPerson', 9800), ('minLos', 1), ('promotion', False), ('displayTotalPrice', 9800)])

                to convert to list of dicts this:
lt2 = '''[
    {
        locale: "fr_FR",
        day: "2015-12-01",
        displayPricePerPerson: 9800,
        displayTotalPrice: 9800,
        promotion: false,
        minLos: 1
    },
    {
        locale: "fr_FR",
        day: "2015-12-02",
        displayPricePerPerson: 9800,
        displayTotalPrice: 9800,
        promotion: false,
        minLos: 1
    },
]
'''

    def convert_ECMA_Javascript(st):
        # convert badly formed strings to json format
        import json

        result = re.sub(r'(\w+):',r'"\1":',st)
        result= re.sub(r'false',r'"False"',result)
        result= re.sub(r'true',r'"True"',result)
        result= re.sub(r'\[|\]',r'',result)
        result= re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\b(?!"|-)',r'"\1"',result)
        result= re.sub(r'\n|\t',r'',result)
        li = re.findall(r'{.*?}', result)

        result = []
        for s in li:
            result.append(json.loads(s))

        return result

    pp(convert_ECMA_Javascript(lt2))

    [{'day': '2015-12-01',
      'displayPricePerPerson': '9800',
      'displayTotalPrice': '9800',
      'locale': 'fr_FR',
      'minLos': '1',
      'promotion': 'False'},
     {'day': '2015-12-02',
      'displayPricePerPerson': '9800',
      'displayTotalPrice': '9800',
      'locale': 'fr_FR',
      'minLos': '1',
      'promotion': 'False'}]

    for el in convert_ECMA_Javascript(lt2):
        for k,v in el.items():
            print(k,":", v)

    day : 2015-12-01
    displayPricePerPerson : 9800
    minLos : 1
    promotion : False
    displayTotalPrice : 9800
    locale : fr_FR
    day : 2015-12-02
    displayPricePerPerson : 9800
    minLos : 1
    promotion : False
    displayTotalPrice : 9800
    locale : fr_FR
```

Comment: Yes, what OP has is valid ECMA script / Javascript, and not JSON.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there a way to convert this Javascriipt to JSON before looping over the response? I am not sure I could use stringify() in robot framework?

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs i have converted these dicts to json just putting quotes around the keys, and changing false to False. So it looks like keys should be put into quotes, and booleans made pythonic ie be uppercased.

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs I have written lines how to convert to json. take a look.

Comment: thanks indeed I should convert the response into  JSON first, I thought it was alreay a JSON form

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs thank you for you patiance. Now convesion works. parsed_json = json.loads(li[0])

print(parsed_json['day'])

2015-12-01

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs put it into a function. I guess that's it.

Comment: thanks, in fact I used dump function of the JSON module : re = json.dumps(data, skipkeys=False)

Comment: it seems that the repsonse I am having is JSONP and not JOSN

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs i found this, may be it will be of help. http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the actual data is valid JSON (the data in the question isn't), once you call `To JSON`, the data that is returned is a list of dictionaries that can be iterated over. You should be able to loop over them without any further conversion.

For example:

```
${JSON}=    To JSON    ${resp.content}
:FOR    ${item}    IN    @{JSON}
    \  log    locale: ${item["locale"]}
```

The above will log one line for each dictionary in the JSON data.